# how to get maven project version in logback.xml

Tags: java, logging, log4j, logback

how can i get the maven project version in logback configuration file since I want to log the project version number.
here is the maven file.

```
<groupId>com.shanil</groupId>
<artifactId>loggingDemo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>loggingDemo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot logging</description>
```

here is the logback configuration file

```
 <appender name="Console"
    class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
        <Pattern>
            CEF:1|CompanyTest|%X{nameofapplication:-loggingDemo}|**version number here**| %msg%n 
        </Pattern>
    </layout>
</appender>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a build step which takes a *template* logback file and populates some placeholders. From logback's perspective, the version would then just be an arbitrary string, just like the `CEF:1|CompanyTest|` part.

Maven resources plugin should be able to achieve this. It uses "filtering" to replace placeholders.

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <includes>
                <include>some/dir/logback.template.xml</include>
            </includes>
            <targetPath>some/outputpath/logback.xml</targetPath>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

Your logback template would look something like this

```
<Pattern>
    CEF:1|CompanyTest|%X{nameofapplication:-loggingDemo}|${project.artifact.id}| %msg%n 
</Pattern>
```

You might want to play around with changing the delimiter; not sure whether the default format `${...}` will mix well with logback's format `{...}`. So you could change the delimiter to `**` or something.

Comment: the above solution should have worked but i tried out so may times and nothing works .it does not modifies logback config file. if you don't mind it would great if you could provide a sample project via git or something and it would really help me a lot .Thanks

Comment: thx for the idea. I made it work. the issue was with the delimiter

Answer (score 1):

here is the answer .
pattern

```
   <Pattern>
    CEF:1|CompanyTest|%X{nameofapplication:-loggingDemo}|${project.artifact.id}| %msg%n 
</Pattern>
```

pom.xml

```
     <resources>
              <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>logback-test.xml</include>
                </includes>
             </resource>

        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <useDefaultDelimiters>false</useDefaultDelimiters>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <delimiters>
                        <delimiter>${*}</delimiter>
                    </delimiters>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
      </plugins>
```